# Changing field names in REST API response

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Hi I'm a newbie so I may not understand high level solutions !

So coming to the point I want to send a response for a REST API. So what basically happening is that I'm returning an object from a method and then the fields of those objects along with their corresponding values get displayed in the API response.

To be clear lets say we have a class defined as

```
Class Sample
{
    String fruit;
    int cost;
}
```

Now lets say we have an object of the above class (Sample abc).
Also we have a method as below:

```
@RequestMapping(/inventory)
public Sample getInventory()
{
    Sample abc = new Sample();
    ----Some processing----
    return abc;
}
```

So the response I'm getting is that

```
{
    "fruit":"apple",
    "cost":100
}
```

Now what I want is "fruit.name" in the response, but obviously I can't have a field with that name(having dot or @ characters) !

```
{
    "fruit.name":"apple",
    "cost@Dollars":100
}
```

So is there any way with the help of which I can get this kind of response ?

Comment: You can achieve that easily with a custom serializer. What are you using? Jackson?

Comment: Yep probably. because the pom.xml says: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency> along with other jackson related dependencies ..

Comment: The given answer is an easier solution. Unless you want to add the `.` or `@` programatically, in case there are many fields for every class you create. Then it would be better with a custom serializer. If that is the case, let me know and I can give you an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) you could use @JsonProperty

```
public class Sample {
  @JsonProperty("fruit.name")
  public String fruit;
  @JsonProperty("cost@Dollars")
  public int cost; 
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Cheers.

Comment: I think it will send both the fields `fruit` and `fruit.name` in the response?